# GNOME 2.16.0: desktop frozen (redhat 5.8)

Tags: gnome, desktop, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have a user whose desktop is frozen.  We're running Redhat 5.8.  Gnome version is 2.16.0.

Clicking the icons does nothing.  The menus on the toolbar work.  If I try to launch nautilus from the command line, the process starts, but nothing appears.

It appears to be a configuration issue.  I killed the entire session and started a new one, but that didn't fix the problem.

For what it's worth, everything is accessed by VNC.

UPDATE:
The errors in .xsession-errors are uninformative, insofar as I have the same errors on my account, and there's nothing wrong there.

Very strangely, if I put absolutely everything except .cshrc and .vnc into a dummy folder, then start VNC (and hence a desktop session), the problem persists!  I have no idea how that could happen, since there's nothing unusual in his .cshrc or .vnc/xstartup files.

Comment: Anything interesting in the user's `~/.xsession-errors`?

Comment: Does the computer think the monitor is larger than it actually is, thus throwing up windows outside of the visible area?

Comment: Jenny D--that's not the issue, since this is all done by VNC, and the size is set in advance.